# Getting OAID as 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 in Apps flyer and Huawei conversion tracking

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appsflyer

I am using Huawei Ads and implemented Appsflyer third party tracking platform for conversion tracking. Here for few devices i am getting OAID as 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.What is the reason ? I need to configure anything extra in the portal?

Answer (score 2):

- In Huawei devices, **If a user disables personalized ads**, OAID is set
  to a value containing only zeros, for example,
  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
- In non-Huawei devices if OAID
  is not available **GAID** will be collected.

[image]

For more details about Apps-flyer integration please check below links:

[AppsFlyer](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/promotion/appsflyer-0000001122291488)

[Android OAID implementation in the SDK](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006278797-Android-OAID-implementation-in-the-SDK)